# How to rebase on a branch and advance that branch pointer

Tags: git, git-rebase

Is there a way to both rebase and move branch forward in one command? I'm trying to run the following while having $DESTINATION checked out:

```
git rebase --no-ff --interactive --onto "$DESTINATION" "$IMPORT_BEGIN" "$IMPORT_END"
```

but after it completes, I end up in a detached head state. Is there any way I can have a result similar to cherry-picking that range - that is when it completes to have $DESTINATION pointing at the last rebased commit?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're asking:

```
git checkout $DESTINATION        # assuming here that that's a branch name, not a hash
git cherry-pick $IMPORT_BEGIN..$IMPORT_END
```

Note that if `$IMPORT_BEGIN` names the first commit you want to have cherry-picked, then you will need to use `${IMPORT_BEGIN}~1` instead - like many other `git` commands, `cherry-pick` interprets the range `<begin>..<end>` to mean "all commits after `<begin>` up to and including `<end>`".

If you check out the branch before hand (as opposed to checking out by hash, resulting in a detached head), then `cherry-pick` will automatically advance the branch head as it goes.

Edit: In order to use `rebase` to do this, let's assume the commits you want to replicate are on a branch named `devel` (in other words, `$IMPORT_END=devel`, not a hash - using hashes instead of branches is how you end up with a detached head), and you want to move these commits onto `master`. In that case, you can do this:

```
git checkout devel
git rebase --onto master $IMPORT_BEGIN..$IMPORT_END
```

That will copy the commits, but it does not advance the `master` branch to the new version of `$IMPORT_END`, which it seems is your desired final state. In order to accomplish that, you would have to follow the above with:

```
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only devel
```

`devel` will have been updated by the `rebase` to point to the new commit, and the `merge` will now make `master` point to the same place.

Comment: Any chance it can be done with `rebase`? I'm relying on the rebase continue/abort mechanism to work later on. With cherry-pick it will not work the same way :(

Comment: You can do it with `rebase`, but it's a different approach, and involves some additional steps. I'll add that to my answer.